# ANT script to replace Value from properties files

Tags: replace, ant

I have below requirement. I have env.properties file which consists of Name/Value pairs and i have one more properties file that is being checked out from SVN to server machine where ANT is installed.

The env.prop file values will not change and remain constant.Example below  shows 3 values but in real time scenario it can contain almost 20 to 30 values.

```
env.properties
DataProvider/JMS_Host/destination.value=127.0.0.1
DataProvider/JMS_Port/destination.value=8987
DataProvider/JMS_User/destination.value=admin

svn.properties
DataProvider/JMS_Host/destination.value=7899000--877@@
DataProvider/JMS_Port/destination.value=
DataProvider/JMS_User/destination.value=@#$%#@@
```

This properties file which is pulled out from svn (svn.properties) will contain the same Name but the values can differ or can be even blank.So aim is to replace the values in svn.properties file with the values from env.properties and end result should be with values from env.prop file.Any help would be really help. There is a similar request as per below link but it servers for only few values but when we have more than 20 to 30 tokens to replace which would be ugly way of implementation.

[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25896141/replace-tokens-from-one-file-to-another-using-ant-script)